# What type of ViewController should I use in this simple iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to make my first Xamarin iPhone app. I have 2 views right now and i'm not sure how to be wire it up and then *switch* to the 2nd one.

1. `AuthenticationViewController`. This is a simple login/create account view.
2. `TabbedViewController`. A few sub views all connected by a tab controller. eg. listview, settings and about/info.

right now, i'm setting the `root = new AuthenticationViewController` and that works fine. just not sure how to swap roots and if this is the correct way to do things.

or should this all be done with a `storyboard` (which i think is an overkill, here)?

Answer (score 1):

The user should always understand where he is. For that Apple suggests animations removing old content and showing new content. One possibility is the `UINavigationController`. You can create an empty `UINavigationController` with your `AuthenticationViewController` as Root. When the authentication succeeded, you can push your new ViewController (which is the `TabbedViewController`) on the stack. If you have a log-off in your `TabbedViewController`, you come back by `PopViewController`.

The other alternative is the `PresentModalViewController`. In the appearing controller you define the modal transitions style. This can be anything and especially for this a FlipView-Animation is in my opinion not a bad choice.

All this exists in Xamarin like in iOS.

StoryBoard is doing the same thing but visualizes what should happen underneath. (like InterfaceBuilder for the ViewController itself).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the `PresentModalViewController` suggestion? Like setting the first root, then swapping the root to the Tab, please?

Comment: You keep the root like it is and then from your `AuthenticationViewController` you create the `TabbedViewController` (in Xamarin with `TabbedViewController controller = new TabbedViewController();  controller.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal; this.PresentViewController(controller, true, null);`

Answer (score 0):

At least in objective-c you can change the root view controller of the window without problems. The only drawback is that you cannot apply transitions doing things this way. But it is totally fine to do so.